# I cannot install packages like skype or steam in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: skype, 16.04

Whenever I try to install skype or steam from the software center they are not there. I went to the terminal to install skype and I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The problem with this is that I don't have any broken packages because I've checked many times. When I try to install skype with aptitude it gives me the solution of deleting MANY system packages. This is what it comes up with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libllvm3.8 : Breaks: libllvm3.8:i386 (!= 1:3.8-2ubuntu3) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 libllvm3.8:i386 : Breaks: libllvm3.8 (!= 1:3.8-2ubuntu1) but 1:3.8-2ubuntu3 is installed.
open: 24; closed: 423; defer: 11; conflict: 28                                 .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                            
1)      a11y-profile-manager-indicator                                          
2)      account-plugin-facebook                                                 
3)      account-plugin-flickr                                                   
4)      account-plugin-google                                                   
5)      activity-log-manager                                                    
6)      adwaita-icon-theme                                                      
7)      aisleriot                                                               
8)      appmenu-qt5                                                             
9)      apport-gtk                                                              
10)     apturl                                                                  
11)     arc-theme                                                               
12)     bamfdaemon                                                              
13)     baobab                                                                  
14)     checkbox-converged                                                      
15)     checkbox-gui                                                            
16)     cheese                                                                  
17)     compiz                                                                  
18)     compiz-gnome                                                            
19)     compiz-plugins-default                                                  
20)     deja-dup                                                                
21)     dosbox                                                                  
22)     eog                                                                     
23)     evince                                                                  
24)     evolution-data-server                                                   
25)     file-roller                                                             
26)     fwupd                                                                   
27)     gcr                                                                     
28)     gdebi                                                                   
29)     gedit                                                                   
30)     gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1                                                
31)     gir1.2-gtk-3.0                                                          
32)     gir1.2-gtksource-3.0                                                    
33)     gir1.2-peas-1.0                                                         
34)     gir1.2-rb-3.0                                                           
35)     gir1.2-totem-1.0                                                        
36)     gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0                                               
37)     gir1.2-vte-2.91                                                         
38)     gir1.2-webkit2-4.0                                                      
39)     gir1.2-wnck-3.0                                                         
40)     gkbd-capplet                                                            
41)     gnome-bluetooth                                                         
42)     gnome-calculator                                                        
43)     gnome-calendar                                                          
44)     gnome-disk-utility                                                      
45)     gnome-font-viewer                                                       
46)     gnome-icon-theme                                                        
47)     gnome-keyring                                                           
48)     gnome-mahjongg                                                          
49)     gnome-mines                                                             
50)     gnome-orca                                                              
51)     gnome-power-manager                                                     
52)     gnome-screensaver                                                       
53)     gnome-screenshot                                                        
54)     gnome-session-bin                                                       
55)     gnome-session-canberra                                                  
56)     gnome-software                                                          
57)     gnome-sudoku                                                            
58)     gnome-system-log                                                        
59)     gnome-system-monitor                                                    
60)     gnome-terminal                                                          
61)     gnome-themes-standard                                                   
62)     gnome-themes-standard-data                                              
63)     gnome-user-guide                                                        
64)     gnome-user-share                                                        
65)     gnupg-agent                                                             
66)     gnupg2                                                                  
67)     grilo-plugins-0.2-base                                                  
68)     gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0                                                
69)     gstreamer1.0-libav                                                      
70)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad                                                
71)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad                                           
72)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers                                   
73)     gucharmap                                                               
74)     gvfs                                                                    
75)     gvfs-backends                                                           
76)     gvfs-daemons                                                            
77)     gvfs-fuse                                                               
78)     hud                                                                     
79)     humanity-icon-theme                                                     
80)     ibus                                                                    
81)     ibus-gtk3                                                               
82)     ibus-table                                                              
83)     indicator-application                                                   
84)     indicator-appmenu                                                       
85)     indicator-bluetooth                                                     
86)     indicator-keyboard                                                      
87)     indicator-printers                                                      
88)     language-selector-gnome                                                 
89)     libaccount-plugin-1.0-0                                                 
90)     libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth                                         
91)     libaccount-plugin-google                                                
92)     libappindicator3-1                                                      
93)     libavahi-ui-gtk3-0                                                      
94)     libavfilter-ffmpeg5                                                     
95)     libcanberra-gtk3-0                                                      
96)     libcanberra-gtk3-module                                                 
97)     libcheese-gtk25                                                         
98)     libcheese8                                                              
99)     libclutter-1.0-0                                                        
100     libclutter-gst-3.0-0                                                    
101     libclutter-gtk-1.0-0                                                    
102     libcogl-pango20                                                         
103     libcogl-path20                                                          
104     libcogl20                                                               
105     libedataserverui-1.2-1                                                  
106     libegl1-mesa                                                            
107     libevdocument3-4                                                        
108     libevview3-3                                                            
109     libgail-3-0                                                             
110     libgcr-ui-3-1                                                           
111     libgl1-mesa-dri                                                         
112     libgl1-mesa-glx                                                         
113     libglew1.13                                                             
114     libglewmx1.13                                                           
115     libglu1-mesa                                                            
116     libgmime-2.6-0                                                          
117     libgnome-bluetooth13                                                    
118     libgnome-desktop-3-12                                                   
119     libgnomekbd8                                                            
120     libgpgme11                                                              
121     libgrilo-0.2-1                                                          
122     libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0                                           
123     libgtk-3-0                                                              
124     libgtk-3-bin                                                            
125     libgtk-3-common                                                         
126     libgtkglext1                                                            
127     libgtkmm-3.0-1v5                                                        
128     libgtksourceview-3.0-1                                                  
129     libgtkspell3-3-0                                                        
130     libgucharmap-2-90-7                                                     
131     libgweather-3-6                                                         
132     libido3-0.1-0                                                           
133     libindicator3-7                                                         
134     libllvm3.8                                                              
135     libmetacity-private3a                                                   
136     libnautilus-extension1a                                                 
137     libnm-gtk0                                                              
138     libnma0                                                                 
139     libnux-4.0-0                                                            
140     libopencv-calib3d2.4v5                                                  
141     libopencv-contrib2.4v5                                                  
142     libopencv-core2.4v5                                                     
143     libopencv-features2d2.4v5                                               
144     libopencv-flann2.4v5                                                    
145     libopencv-highgui2.4v5                                                  
146     libopencv-imgproc2.4v5                                                  
147     libopencv-legacy2.4v5                                                   
148     libopencv-ml2.4v5                                                       
149     libopencv-objdetect2.4v5                                                
150     libopencv-video2.4v5                                                    
151     liboxideqt-qmlplugin                                                    
152     liboxideqtcore0                                                         
153     liboxideqtquick0                                                        
154     libpeas-1.0-0                                                           
155     libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader                                             
156     libqt5feedback5                                                         
157     libqt5gui5                                                              
158     libqt5multimedia5                                                       
159     libqt5opengl5                                                           
160     libqt5printsupport5                                                     
161     libqt5quick5                                                            
162     libqt5quicktest5                                                        
163     libqt5svg5                                                              
164     libqt5webkit5                                                           
165     libqt5widgets5                                                          
166     libqt5x11extras5                                                        
167     libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer                                   
168     libreoffice-base-core                                                   
169     libreoffice-calc                                                        
170     libreoffice-core                                                        
171     libreoffice-draw                                                        
172     libreoffice-gnome                                                       
173     libreoffice-gtk                                                         
174     libreoffice-help-en-us                                                  
175     libreoffice-impress                                                     
176     libreoffice-math                                                        
177     libreoffice-ogltrans                                                    
178     libreoffice-pdfimport                                                   
179     libreoffice-writer                                                      
180     librhythmbox-core9                                                      
181     libtimezonemap1                                                         
182     libtotem-plparser18                                                     
183     libtotem0                                                               
184     libubuntugestures5                                                      
185     libubuntutoolkit5                                                       
186     libunity-control-center1                                                
187     libunity-core-6.0-9                                                     
188     libunity-gtk3-parser0                                                   
189     libunity-misc4                                                          
190     libunity-settings-daemon1                                               
191     libunity-webapps0                                                       
192     libvte-2.91-0                                                           
193     libwayland-egl1-mesa                                                    
194     libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37                                                    
195     libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2                                               
196     libwnck-3-0                                                             
197     libxatracker2                                                           
198     libyelp0                                                                
199     light-themes                                                            
200     mesa-vdpau-drivers                                                      
201     mousetweaks                                                             
202     nautilus                                                                
203     nautilus-sendto                                                         
204     nautilus-share                                                          
205     network-manager-gnome                                                   
206     network-manager-pptp-gnome                                              
207     notify-osd                                                              
208     nux-tools                                                               
209     onboard                                                                 
210     onboard-data                                                            
211     pinentry-gnome3                                                         
212     policykit-1-gnome                                                       
213     pyotherside                                                             
214     python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets                                           
215     python3-uno                                                             
216     qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside                                           
217     qml-module-qtfeedback                                                   
218     qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects                                           
219     qml-module-qtquick-layouts                                              
220     qml-module-qtquick-window2                                              
221     qml-module-qtquick2                                                     
222     qml-module-qttest                                                       
223     qml-module-ubuntu-components                                            
224     qml-module-ubuntu-layouts                                               
225     qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts                                        
226     qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics                                    
227     qml-module-ubuntu-test                                                  
228     qml-module-ubuntu-web                                                   
229     qmlscene                                                                
230     qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin                                          
231     qtdeclarative5-dev-tools                                                
232     qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin                                          
233     qtdeclarative5-test-plugin                                              
234     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin                                 
235     remmina                                                                 
236     remmina-plugin-rdp                                                      
237     remmina-plugin-vnc                                                      
238     rhythmbox                                                               
239     rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist                                              
240     rhythmbox-plugins                                                       
241     seahorse                                                                
242     session-shortcuts                                                       
243     sessioninstaller                                                        
244     shotwell                                                                
245     signon-ui                                                               
246     signon-ui-x11                                                           
247     simple-scan                                                             
248     software-properties-gtk                                                 
249     synaptic                                                                
250     system-config-printer-gnome                                             
251     totem                                                                   
252     totem-plugins                                                           
253     transmission-gtk                                                        
254     ubuntu-artwork                                                          
255     ubuntu-desktop                                                          
256     ubuntu-docs                                                             
257     ubuntu-mono                                                             
258     ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk                                             
259     ubuntu-session                                                          
260     ubuntu-software                                                         
261     unity                                                                   
262     unity-asset-pool                                                        
263     unity-control-center                                                    
264     unity-control-center-signon                                             
265     unity-greeter                                                           
266     unity-gtk3-module                                                       
267     unity-scope-calculator                                                  
268     unity-scope-gdrive                                                      
269     unity-scope-manpages                                                    
270     unity-services                                                          
271     unity-settings-daemon                                                   
272     unity-tweak-tool                                                        
273     unity-webapps-common                                                    
274     unity-webapps-qml                                                       
275     unity-webapps-service                                                   
276     update-manager                                                          
277     update-notifier                                                         
278     usb-creator-gtk                                                         
279     va-driver-all                                                           
280     vdpau-driver-all                                                        
281     vdpau-va-driver                                                         
282     vino                                                                    
283     vlc                                                                     
284     webapp-container                                                        
285     webbrowser-app                                                          
286     x11-utils                                                               
287     xdg-user-dirs-gtk                                                       
288     xdiagnose                                                               
289     xorg                                                                    
290     xserver-xorg                                                            
291     xserver-xorg-core                                                       
292     xserver-xorg-input-all                                                  
293     xserver-xorg-input-evdev                                                
294     xserver-xorg-input-synaptics                                            
295     xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse                                              
296     xserver-xorg-input-wacom                                                
297     xserver-
```

...and many other packages that cannot fit into this post.

Comment: How did you install 16.04? Fresh install or upgraded from 14.04 or 15.10? Are you sure that the system is fully updated (`sudo apt full-upgrade`)? Btw, not shown in Ubuntu Software is a [known issue](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1567630).

Comment: Another question: is the _universe_ pocket enabled in **Software & Updates**?

Comment: Yeah the universe is enabled and since it is a known issue then I see how that could've happened. Also the reason it showed all those errors is because Ubuntu installed wrong so I reinstalled it through terminal and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : `sudo apt-cache search skype`

After that you see `skype-bin`

Then : `sudo apt-get install -y skype-bin`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded the .deb packages from the websites, not through Ubuntu's software center. On skype.com, you download the 12.04 multiarch version. It works fine on Ubuntu 16.04.

The same with Steam and other utilities missing in the Software Center.

You can open the .deb packages by "Open with... --> Software Center", or `sudo dpkg -i package.deb` in the terminal.

**Edit:** As it's mentioned in the comment, sometimes you have to follow up with `sudo dpkg -f install` to include the missing 32-bit binaries on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: It's approximately the same dependencies, so it's unlikely that struggling with the .deb from the Skype website would make a difference.

Comment: As I have the 64bit OS, after installing skype, I had to issue a `dpkg -f install` to install the missing i386 dependencies.