# Skype install into Ubuntu 17.04 64bit

Tags: software-installation, skype

How do I install Skype in Ubuntu 17.04 64 bit?

I am just running it from an original RPM folder, with a short cut to the  launcher.

I cannot get the .DEB or .RPM packages to install.

What line do I need to use in the repository section for it to appear in the software manager?

Comment: what error are you getting? which version are you trying to install?

Comment: no error, just wont install. click the button marked install, and nothing happens

Comment: what button? in software center?

Comment: The button on the top left hand side Called  "INSTALL" OF THE SOFTWARE MANAGER BELOW A purple SIDEWAYS BOX with a picture of a half cog. Above that is the program title I m trying to install.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762147/i-cannot-install-packages-like-skype-or-steam-in-ubuntu-16-04/763252#763252

Answer (score 3):

> Older versions of the Skype desktop app for Linux will no longer work
>   from July 1 this year, Skype has said.
>
> “All Skype for Linux client version 4.3 and older will be retired on
>   July 1, 2017. To keep chatting, please install the latest version of
>   Skype for Linux,” a notice on the Skype for Linux download page reads.

To install the latest Skype, download it from [here](https://go.skype.com/linux.deb)

once downloaded you can either use [Gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) to install it, or just Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Skype website and choose the version for your OS (Deb for Ubuntu). When it's downloaded, open the .deb file and it will open Software Center. Just click "İnstall".

(There's a bug with Software Center that install button doesn't work. I suggest you install GDebi package manager. You can find it in the Software Center, or you can install via terminal. It can install deb packages for you if Software Center doesn't work.)

Comment: Did that succeed? I installed skypeforlinux from the official repos, version 5.4.0.1 (same as on Skype's download page).  It does not display an indicator, and once closed, cannot be revived. So, it does not work for me on 17.04 64bit (Unity). Ghetto-Skype, however, works (but also no indicator).